# Insert unique rows only and update rows that already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table called 'Day Zero' which contains a listing_id column, address column and status column. The listing_id is always unique and is an int data type. The status column in every row is Existing

Each day, I get two text files, one called Listings, and the Other called Sold, and I use BULK insert to import the data directly into the table, the data is these two text files contains only a listing_id and address column.

What I'm trying to figure out, is how to import the data from these files into the table with the following logic:

1. if `listing_id` exists in `day zero` file and `listings` file then do not import new row and change `status` on existing row to `'updated'`
2. if `listing_id` does not exist in `day zero` file and exists in listing_file then insert new row and change `status` to `'new'`
3. if listing id exists in `day zero` file and exists in `sold_file` then do not import new row and change `status` on existing row to `'sold'`
4. if `listing_id` does not exist in `day zero` file and exists in `sold_file` then insert new row and change `status` to `'unknown_sale_event'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load each file in a separate temporary table, and then implement the logic using [SQL Server's `merge` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

The following query merges data from the LISTINGS file (assuming that the file was loaded in temporary table `#listings`):

```
merge day_zero d 
using #listings l on (l.listing_id = d.listing_id)
when matched
    then update set d.status = 'UPDATED'
when not matched by target
    then insert(listing_id, address, status) 
    values(l.listing_id, address, 'NEW')
```

And here is the equivalent query for the SALES file:

```
merge day_zero d 
using #sold s on (s.listing_id = d.listing_id)
when matched
    then update set d.status = 'SOLD'
when not matched by target
    then insert(listing_id, address, status) 
    values(s.listing_id, address, 'UNKNOWN_SALE_EVENT')
```